# MR parallel processing failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a compound index on a table on which map reduce runs

```
db.jobs.createIndex({
    Name: "text",
    Line1: "text",
    City: "text",
    State: "text",
    Zip: "text",
    PropertyId: "text",
    Line2: "text",
    JobId: 1,
    JobOwner: 1,
    Amount: 1
},   {
 weights: {
   Name: 100,
 },
 name: "custom_text_index"
```

})

And there is an entry where **Line1 ,which has a text index**, is around **370KB** and because of this mapreduce is failing with below errors

```
2018-04-22T13:34:50.666+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: map reduce failed:{
"code" : 17280,
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "MR parallel processing failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing  371495 { : { Agency_Id: 190.0, PropertyId: \"070720762\", Name: \"MOUNT SINAI SCHOOL OF M...\", code: 17280, codeName: \"KeyTooLong\" }"
```

Though mongo doc says [text index can be large](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#text-search-support), is it still valid in case of above compound index? or is it subject to index key limitation of 1024 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

The 1024 bytes limitation applies to all **index entries**. The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit) states

> The total size of an **index entry**, which can include structural
>   overhead depending on the BSON type, must be less than 1024 bytes.

and also

> MongoDB will not insert into an indexed collection any document with
>   an indexed field whose corresponding index entry would exceed the
>   index key limit, and instead, will return an error. Previous versions
>   of MongoDB would insert but not index such documents.

That explains the error you are seeing.

Right next to the statement that you cited from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#storage-requirements-and-performance-costs)

> text indexes can be large.

there's the following, too:

> They contain one **index entry** for each unique post-stemmed word in each indexed field for each document inserted.

So the whole text index can be larger than 1024 bytes, each individual **index entry** in it, however, must not.

That's why I would tend to think that inside your 370kb `Line1` entry there is a word that is longer than 1024 bytes.

In order to exclude the compound index as a potential culprit you could as well change the index to only index the `Line1` entry and see how that goes:

```
db.jobs.createIndex({
    Line1: "text"
}, {
  weights: {
    Name: 100,
  },
  name: "custom_text_index"
})
```

Comment: Thanks. As for index entry for each unique post-stemmed word size exceeding 1024 bytes. I need to double confirm. Mostly I am sure I don't have words exceeding 52 chars in the Line1 field.